# Unable to insert data into partitioned table due to precision loss

Tags: hive, hdfs, impala, hue

I have created an external table partitioning on two columns. The two columns are 'country' and 'state' stored as SEQUENCEFILE.

I am now trying to load the data into the table using the following command in Impala run via Hue editor -

```
load data inpath '/usr/temp/input.txt' 
into table partitioned_user
partition (country = 'US', state = 'CA');
```

I am getting the following error -

**AnalysisException: Partition key value may result in loss of precision. Would need to cast ''US'' to 'VARCHAR(64)' for partition column: country**

What am I doing wrong? The table that I am inserting has columns such as and all are of type VARCHAR(64) - first_name,last_name,country,state.

The file input.txt contains the data only for the first two columns. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: **1.** Hive/Impala use generic `String`, and `Varchar(x)` support is a late and cosmetic addition **2.** Partition keys are managed as _metadata_ (in Metastore DB + in HDFS directory names), not stored in data files, hence they use a different code base, and don't support well anything that's not a plain `String`-with-alphanum-chars or an `Int` **3.** Impala and Hive have a different code base in different languages, what works in Hive may not work in Impala ==> use a `String` for your partitioning keys, and try your commands both in Hive and Impala to see what works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impala does not automatically convert from a larger type to a smaller one.. You must `CAST()` to a `VARCHAR(64)` before inserting to avoid such exception in Impala.

```
partition (country = cast('US' as VARCHAR(64)), state = cast('CA' as VARCHAR(64)))
```

Or use `STRING` datatype in table DDL instead.

Comment: Thank you @leftjoin. It works. Strange thing is I did put up a cast and try, it had failed. I don't know how it got executed successfully now.